# Python/socket: How to send a file to another computer which is on a different network?

Tags: python, sockets

The codes below work if the computers are on the same network. However if these computers are on different networks, the connection timed out.

The codes of **server.py** are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.**", 12345))

s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

f = open("image.jpg", "rb")
datas = f.read(1024)

while datas:
    c.send(datas)
    datas = f.read(1024)

f.close()
print("Done sending...")
```

And the **client.py** includes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.**", 12345))

f = open("recieved.jpg", "wb")

while True:
    datas = s.recv(1024)
    while datas:
        f.write(datas)
        datas = s.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    break
print("Done receiving")
```

I read that, the problem can rise from modem settings. Then i closed the firewall of the network which **server.py** connected on. But still the computer which client.py file is in, can't connect to the other computer.

What should i do, to connect these computers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't override how TCP/IP works.

Comment: Sorry, can you make your remark more clearer?

Comment: There is no way to communicate directly with another machine that is on an inaccessible network.

Comment: What can you suggest to connect these machines indirectly?

Comment: Use a third machine that both can connect to.

Comment: This is a routing problem (the fact that it was ran into from a programming task is irrelevant). Best way to go forward is moving it to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But these machines will be on different places. How can both machines connect to the third machine?

Comment: I guess you're just going to have to figure that out.

Comment: @CristiFati, Thanks, i will look at that page.

Comment: Is setting up an FTP server an option?

Comment: I set up a virtual server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

**server.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 12345)) #if the clients/server are on different network you shall bind to ('', port)

s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

f = open("image.jpg", "rb")
l = os.path.getsize("image.jpg")
m = f.read(l)
c.send_all(m)
f.close()
print("Done sending...")
```

**client.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("server_public_ip", 12345)) # here you must past the public external ipaddress of the server machine, not that local address

f = open("recieved.jpg", "wb")
data = None
while True:
    m = s.recv(1024)
    data = m
    if m:
        while m:
            m = s.recv(1024)
            data += m
        else:
            break
f.write(data)
f.close()
print("Done receiving")
```

**note**: on your **server.py** you are waiting for 10 clients but you accept only one connection you shall put the `c, addr = s.accept()` in a `while` loop

**Update**: If the clients/server are behind a rooter then you have to forward the port on the rooter for that connection

> **Port Forwarding**:

### Works only WITH python 2.X

i've made myself a script to forward port on every OS but the script it too long you can grab it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3XGn7xdfoSNWHNHa0lNNTMtUWc)

then in **server.py**:

```
from port_forwarding import forward_port
```

and before `s = socket.socket ###` put

```
forward_port(port, 'description')
```

don't forget to put the **port_forwarding** script in the same folder of **sever.py**

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain this more? **s.connect(("192.168.1.++", 12345)) # here you must past the public external ipaddress of the server machine, not that local address**. How can i find the public external ipaddress?

Comment: Thanks, i will search for finding the external ipaddress.

Comment: `192.168.1.**` is the local ip of the server, to connect the client to the server from the internet you must know the public ip of the server, you can find that here https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-my-public-ip-address/

Comment: I've edited the answer in the case your server is behind a NAT (rooter)

Comment: Before reading your edited message, I changed the codes as you suggest. And run the program again. But now i'm getting a ConnectionRefusedError. Is this problem related to your updated post which is **Update: If the clients/server are behind a rooter then you have to forward the port on the rooter for that connection**

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, what should i do for that? Should i open the modem page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157681/discussion-between-sp-sp-and-dilde-olupbiten).